# express js can not access to multiple static pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I am following a [toturial](https://vegibit.com/node-js-blog-tutorial/) online which teach you using express.js to access multiple static pages. I have followed the tutorial exactly and type the code exactly what it shows but the code is not working when i try to navigate the website by using the navbar, the server get me the error message as Cannot GET /index.html or Cannot GET /about.html or Cannot GET /contact.html. The code I have so far is as below. I saved all html files in a folder called pages. Should I copy all the html files to public folder? I don't understand what's the point of creating a pages folder in this tutorial.

[image]

```
 const path = require('path');

 const express = require('express');

  const app = new express();

  app.use(express.static('public'));

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/index.html'));
 });

 app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/about.html'));
 });

 app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/contact.html'));
 });

 app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/post.html'));
 });

 app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('App listening on port 4000')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you request `/about.html` then:

- It will match `app.use(express.static('public'));` (because that matches *every* URL)
- It will not match `app.get('/about', (req, res) => {` (because that is different)
- It will match `app.get('/about.html', (req, res) => {` (because that matches it explicitly)

`app.use(express.static('public'));` won't find an `about.html` or an `about` because there are no files of that name in the `public` directory.

`res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/about.html'));` will find `about.html` because the path matches it explicitly.

Comment: I figured out that there are two ways of solving these, first is the create another static assets directory and set it up as app.use(express.static('pages')) and the server will has access to the html files. So it will call express.static middleware two times. Another ways is simply move all html files to public folder. Still don't understand why the tutorial wants to set up the seperate folder Pages for all htmls and did not set up multiple express.static() in order for server to access it. Anyway, I will keep following the tutorial. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register static `pages` directory

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/pages'));
```

Your route should work.

```
app.get('/about.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'about.html'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this way :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname+'/public/', 'pages/post.html'));
```

Comment: `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname+'/public/', 'pages/post.html'));
` — No. `pages` is not a subdirectory of `public`

Comment: `app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` — No. `/public` does not appear in the URL the OP is requesting.

Answer (score -1):

Just you change path like this

For example  `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/pages/', 'index.html'));`

Comment: There is no directory called "page" in the "public" directory.

Comment: yes i accepted my mistake  i have tested in my local env name called page so same code i have posted. now i have changed .

Comment: Re edit: `pages` is not a subdirectory of `public` either. The only subdirectories of `public` are `css`, `img`, `js` and `vendor`.

Answer (score -1):

move your pages folder to public folder then :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```